# Facebook Suggested Events.

Tags: facebook, events, fbml

Is their a way to get the list of "Suggested Events" that facebook creates for each user?  I know that facebook has the feature to show you a list of suggested events that is basically a list of all the events your friends are invited to.  I am looking for some FBML or other Facebook API to get this list of suggested events?

Comment: same here, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Never found it.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with the public Graph API, sorry.